# SVG Rotating on Axis

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I've tried to follow the forums to fix the issue I'm having, but I'm having no luck. I am trying to spin this letter on the center axis, but it's going around the page instead.

I added the transform-origin: center center; which appears to be the answer, but it doesn't appear to be affecting my animation.

Am I missing a very important line of code here?

**The Code**

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28.2878in" height="8.5in" viewBox="0 0 2036.7197 612"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#010101;}</style></defs><title>StableLogo-Wordmark</title>

<!-- BIG S -->
<path class="big-s spin-this" transform="translate(-154 -131)" d="M362.2168,367.2317c23.8106,16.6907,51.0516,32.82,83.83,32.82,32.1888,0,56.8072-10.392,56.8072-33.4934,0-22.7209-10.6044-34.0863-70.4407-43.93-59.8364-10.6044-89.757-33.7058-89.757-78.3966,0-46.9588,39.96-79.6635,99.4161-79.6635,36.6579,0,63.8458,7.9425,97.4489,28.7153l-18.0235,37.88c-33.9085-17.7179-47.9607-24.0272-78.4851-24.0272-30.6717,0-49.227,14.75-49.227,35.9591,0,19.3162,10.6044,28.7841,67.4117,38.6325,65.1385,10.98,93.5422,35.2179,93.5422,81.8012,0,49.6124-39.7691,83.9606-109.8293,83.9606-38.3944,0-79.8883-17.5373-102.94-38.04Z">

 <style>
 
      .spin-this {
       -webkit-animation-name: spin;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
       -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
       -moz-animation-name: spin;
       -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
       -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
       -ms-animation-name: spin;
       -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
       -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
       
       animation-name: spin;
       animation-duration: 4000ms;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       animation-timing-function: linear;

       transform-origin: center center!important; 
      }

   @-ms-keyframes spin {
       from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
       to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  }

   }
   @-moz-keyframes spin {
       from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
       to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes spin {
       from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
       to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
   }
   @keyframes spin {
       from {
           transform:rotate(0deg);
       }
       to {
           transform:rotate(360deg);
       }
   }
 </style>


</path>

</svg>
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the issue may be in your SVG itself, not the animation. Are you trying to rotate around the centre of the `S`? Beacuse the `S` is off centre in the SVG, which will lead to the animation you're seeing.

Comment: Add `transform-box: fill-box;` to `.spin-this`  Please read this: [MDN - transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box). Without `transform-box: fill-box;` the letter is rotated around the center of the svg element.

Comment: THANK YOU! Transform-box: fill-box fixed this right up.

Comment: Bare in mind `transform-box` has limited browser support, be sure to check the link in enxaneta's comment. At the moment it's unsupported in all Microsoft browsers.

Comment: @DBS Although `transform-box` has limited browser support , in those browsers without support the letter will rotate correctly around it's center.